# Where'd My Desktop Go?

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (maybe .10, both LTS, as I usually keep everything updated) to Jammy Jellyfish 22.04.

I, certainly naively, assumed that all the files, folders, and shortcuts normally visible from my previous desktop on Studio 20.04/.10 would still be there, albeit under a new o.s.

Can you assist me in "re-building" my previous desktop view, please?

It's probably simple, but I could use some assistance.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more detailed regardging the help you need? As I read your question, you are asking for help to put files/folders/shortcuts on your desktop.

Comment: Certainly! Thank you! Yes, I just want to be able to see all the files/folders/shortcuts I used to see on my desktop before the Jellyfish install. I assume I should just be able to put a shortcut to my "desktop" folder on the new layout.